# Reopen Sales Order in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, erp

I have accidentally closed a Sales Order in Netsuite. Any ideas how to reopen the SO? Or change the status back to pending fulfillment?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a place to discuss and seek help on specific programming related issues and problems - not application support. For guidance on how to ask a good question, [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi. Sorry for that. Anyhow, I;ve already have an answer to this.

Comment: You do know they have application support ... right?

Comment: We do not sign direct support with Netsuite. Only through our partner, however we will be charged for every question asked.

Comment: Oh, so we're free support now. Gotcha.

Comment: Well, in a way we all benefit from this free community. In the future, people who stumble upon the same problem can look up this post.

Comment: This question also applies when setting the status field via JavaScript. Very glad someone asked this.

Answer (score 5):

I just got a solution. That is the uncheck the Closed checkbox on all the items in the Sales Order. That will switch the status back to Pending Fulfillment.

Comment: As long as you open at least one unfulfilled item, this also works.